# Recreational problems in set theory?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, soft-question, recreational-mathematics, big-list

Most areas of maths that I can think of have a number of fun, recreational problems that come under their category. Nothing deep: number theoretic stuff in olympiads, integrals, limits, products, series in real/complex analysis, colouring/construction problems in graph theory, cool little existence problems in group theory, the list goes on.

Set theory has always felt solely research bent to me - most of the related questions posted on here seem quite deep, or arising from serious study.

Are there any "fun" set-theoretic problems out there? If so it would be interesting to gather a little collection here.

Comment: I daresay "fun" is a subjective notion. For example, many users here find the sort of deep research you mention fun. Others enjoy playing with concepts with a minimum of research, for the sake of a personal challenge, and can find themselves fairly deep in the subject matter as a result.

Comment: @CameronBuie: "fairly deep in the subject matter" sounds like a euphemism for something rather unpleasant. What did you have in mind?

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sci.math/dq8Pp2wuAyQ I am actually surprised this is so old.

Comment: http://qcpages.qc.cuny.edu/~rmiller/abstracts/Hardin-Taylor.pdf

Comment: @Rob: I didn't really mean anything unpleasant. Such hobbyism can lead to the development of some expertise in areas of inquiry. At worst, one finds oneself attempting to accomplish a provably impossible task, but as-needed research is a nice way out of such bogs.

Comment: @CameronBuie: forgive me, my comment was light-hearted: I knew you didn't mean anything unpleasant, but was just pointing out a possible frivolous misreading. I'll mop my frivolities up shortly.

Comment: @Rob: Nothing wrong with a bit of frivolity. Thanks for helping me make sure I wasn't misleading!

Comment: There are tons of "fun" questions in set theory, that can be tackled with elementary methods. Construct a subset of $\mathbb R^2$ that intersects every line in precisely two points, construct a universal graph, prove basic facts about non-standard analysis, formulate a winning strategy for a given game, prove various covering properties, fiddle with Ramsey type theorems, ...

Answer (score 3):

Here's a good one: find an explicit bijection between two intervals [0,1] and [0,1).

Comment: Bonus: keep going down this path and you can wind up at Banach-Tarski. (IIRC, there's a great old _Mathematical Intelligencer_ article about this)

Comment: Well, bijection between [0,1] and [0,2] is simpler...

Answer (score 2):

I think it's kinda fun to see how so many things elegantly follow from definitions or axioms:

- The axiom of regularity says that every nonempty set $x$ has an element $y$ that is disjoint from $x$:
  $$
  \forall x : (x\neq \emptyset \rightarrow \exists y\in x : (y\cap x= \emptyset ))
  $$
  Conclude that:

  - $a \notin a$
  - $a \notin b$ or $b \notin a$
  - There is no infinite sequence $a_1 \ni a_2 \ni a_3 \dots$
- An *ordinal number* is a set $\alpha$ that is

  - [transitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_set), that is, for every $x \in \alpha$, we have $x \subseteq \alpha$, and
  - totally ordered w.r.t. set inclusion, that is, for every $x, y \in \alpha$ we have $x \subseteq y$ or $y \subseteq x$.

  Show that for any $\beta \in \alpha$, $\beta$ is an ordinal number as well.

  I find this one especially cute since

  > to show that $\beta$ is transitive, you need the fact that $\alpha$ is ordered w.r.t. set includion, and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you feel like using the axiom of choice, first ask yourself whether you could build a choice function instead. This yields fun problems more often than not.

Answer (score 0):

Fast growing hierarchy? If that doesn't count as set theory, you can try to define large countable ordinals, or just large cardinals. And don't forget Hamkins, the king of recreational set theory!